# How to plot the fourier transform of this period sequence?

Tags: python, fft

I have 64 values of the period sequence 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 29, 23, 11, 22, 9, 18, 1, 2, ...  I compute its fourier transform using

```
from scipy import fft, ifft
x = [(2**i) % 35 for i in range(64)]
y = fft(x)
```

Can you show me an example of how to plot these y values so I can look at the spikes?  I would like to plot only 64 values, not more than that.  What else do I need for a building a plot myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib is one of the most simple and widely used Python modules for plotting graphs.

If you have x and y as 2 lists, corresponding to x and y coordinates, then you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

It appears that your code will already generate 64 values, as you want.

By running your code and plotting the corresponding graph, one obtains:

[image: Scatter plot of x against y.]

If you wish to actually connect the points then `plt.plot(x,y)` can be used instead of `plt.scatter(x,y)`, but it will only work well if your x and y coordinates are ordered in ascending order. Below is some code to allow that:

```
from scipy import fft, ifft
x = [(2**i) % 35 for i in range(64)]
y = fft(x)
y = [n for _,n in sorted(zip(x,y))]
x.sort()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following graph:

[image: Plot of x against y, sorted accordingly.]

Comment: Thanks for showing this.  But the graph doesn't quite look like what I expected to see.  I think that graphing the Fourier Transform requires more than this, which is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: I'd then suggest instead wording your question to ask about how to calculate the specific type of Fourier transform you're after, in Python. Your question seems to only asking about plotting. Also, scipy.fft(x) does calculate the Fourier transform for the sequence you've inputted. If it's not what you expected to see then it's due to x not being what you intended.